# NextJS13 & URQL GraphQL Client --> Redirect in common error handler

Tags: next.js, next.js13, urql

I'm trying out a NextJS-14 Application.
I'm using on the client side URQL as the GraphQL Client. The URQL Client is created on the root layout.

There you can define an [error handler](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/core/):

```
mapExchange({
  onError(error, operation) {
    console.log(`The operation ${operation.key} has errored with:`, error);
    // If Error === A --> Redirect to /login
  },
});
```

In this common error handler, I would like to redirect to a dedicated page.

I've tried is with `useRouter().push("/...")` or `redirect("/...") (from next/navigation)`
In both cases, I received a RuntimeError.

useRouter() --> Hook not accessible outside the function

redirect() --> `Unhandled Runtime Error Error: NEXT_REDIRECT`